# every other day, week, month

Tags: phrase-meaning

We say *every other day/week/month*.

Is *every other second/minute/hour* or *every other year/decade/century* correct?

Comment: Sure. Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: Wow. I'm pleased to learn that they are used like this. Do they sound natural?

Comment: It depends on the context. I can't think of many things that are only done "every other decade," so I don't hear that very often. But in the right context, it would be fine. For example, "Paraguay holds a census every twenty years, during the year that ends with 5 of every other decade," or, "Make sure the patient gets her blood pressure checked at least once every other hour until she leaves the ICU."

Answer (score 2):

**"every other"** can be used with mostly anything:

- Every other day/week/month/year/decade/century/second/minute/hour
- Every other trip/book/car/town/person/animal/ship/problem/planet/etc.

[**Merriam-Webster**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/every%20other) defines **"every other"** as:

- *all those that are different or separate from the person or thing that has already been mentioned*
- *used to say that some repeated activity, event, etc., alternately happens and does not happen in consecutive named periods*

[**TheFreeDictionary**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+other) has more definitions:

- *person or thing every second or alternate person or thing*
- *omitting the next but including the one after that, as a series or repetition of something*
- *happening or existing regularly on every second one of the things you are counting*
- *every second one in a series*
- *each alternate*